# Is it required to call net time repeatedly for synchronization on network failure

Tags: time, timer, synchronization, ntp

We run "net time \server /set /yes" (Batch file) to synchronize clock with an external server. I have couple of concerns as stated below,
a) Do we need to run this batch file daily?
b) Assume if there was a any failure in the network or internet,Do we need to re-run the batch file? 
OR run the batch file periodically?

Please suggest the correct approach as i am not sure, if it's OK to issue above mentioned command  once or schedule it periodically.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Typical drift of "local time" is a few microseconds/second. This can easily accumulate to hundreds of milliseconds per day. Therefore you may - depending on your accuracy requirement - have to do it frequently.

b) A failure on network will prevent the synchronization to happen.

How often shall the synchronization occurr? The underlaying software (w32time) may perform
the synchronization over a long period of time. This procedure may last for hours.

See this article: [NET TIME and w32time](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/w32time/archive/2009/08/07/net-time-and-w32time.aspx)